# UI does not respond to accept any input after first field

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have developed a simple login UI in Xamarin forms. I am having problem where only the top field which is IP Entry functioning properly and other fields after the field does not function as intended. Below I have attached the xaml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Login_Design.CustomRenderer"
             x:Class="Login_Design.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#e6e6e6" x:Name="MainLayout">
            <Grid>
                <StackLayout Padding="0" Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Frame HeightRequest="200" BackgroundColor = "#34ebab"  Padding="0" Margin="0">
                        <Image Source="logoInchz.png" HeightRequest="100" Margin="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Padding="0" Margin="10,180,10,0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="100">
                    <Frame  BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="500" HasShadow="True" Padding="0" Margin="0">

                        <StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Margin="10">
                                <Label Text="SIGN IN" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Padding="0" Margin="15">

                                <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="DarkGray" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" CornerRadius="30">
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Frame BackgroundColor="LightGray" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" CornerRadius="30" Padding="0" Margin="5">
                                            <Image Source="ip.png" Aspect="AspectFill" Margin="0"/>
                                        </Frame>

                                        <local:MyCustomEntry IsReadOnly="False" x:Name="serverEntry " Placeholder="IP Address" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="None" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>


                                <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="DarkGray" Margin="0,15,0,0" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" CornerRadius="30">
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Frame BackgroundColor="LightGray" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" CornerRadius="30" Padding="0" Margin="5">
                                            <Image Source="port.png" Aspect="AspectFill" Margin="0"/>
                                        </Frame>

                                        <local:MyCustomEntry IsReadOnly="False" x:Name="portEntry " Placeholder="Port"  TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="None" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>

                                <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="DarkGray" Margin="0,15,0,0" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" CornerRadius="30">
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Frame BackgroundColor="LightGray" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" CornerRadius="30" Padding="0" Margin="5">
                                            <Image Source="avatar.png" Aspect="AspectFill" Margin="0"/>
                                        </Frame>

                                        <local:MyCustomEntry IsReadOnly="False" x:Name="usernameEntry " Placeholder="Username" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="None" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>

                                <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="DarkGray" Margin="0,15,0,0" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" CornerRadius="30">
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Frame BackgroundColor="LightGray" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" CornerRadius="30" Padding="0" Margin="5">
                                            <Image Source="lock_icon.png" Aspect="AspectFill" Margin="0"/>
                                        </Frame>

                                        <local:MyCustomEntry IsReadOnly="False" x:Name="passwordEntry " Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="None" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>

                                <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <CheckBox x:Name="autoLogin" IsChecked="False" Color="#34ebab" />
                                    <Label Text="Auto Login" TextColor="DarkGray" FontSize="Small" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                </StackLayout>

                                <Button Text="SIGN IN" BackgroundColor="#34ebab" TextColor="White" CornerRadius="30" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

```
namespace Login_Design
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Login_Design.CustomRenderer
{
    public class MyCustomEntry : Entry
    {

    }
}
```

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyCustomEntry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace Login_Design.Droid
{
    public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        public MyEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            //if (Control != null)
            //{
                //GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
                Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                //this.Control.SetBackgroundDrawable(gd);
                //this.Control.SetRawInputType(InputTypes.TextFlagNoSuggestions);
                //Control.SetHintTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(global::Android.Graphics.Color.White));
            //}
        }
    }
```

I tried to removed the StackLayout and tried to modify it but only the first entry field function. I don't see any mistake in the code as well.

Thanks

Comment: did you try replacing your custom Entry with the default Entry? Does it has the same behavior...Find it first cuz it may help you to get on the exact cause of issue

Comment: Or maybe you got an issue with the bindable property of `IsReadOnly`, can you show how its implemented?

Comment: Already tried with default entry but it still was same, I added `IsReadOnly` attribute to check does it fix the problem or not. Anyhow, this got fixed after I redone the xaml code again and I didn't change anything.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Hi, you can have a try with replacing the `MainLayout` with `ScrollView` instead of `StackLayout` to check whether it works.